# Adding Horizontal Line to Graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add horizontal lines to a line graph (sig curve) and I'd like the horizontal lines to meet the line graph and not go past. I have an example of what I'm hoping to do below:

[image: Example of what I hope to create in R]

Included is an example of data. Right now, using `ggplot`, I can create the horizontal lines using `geom_hline` but I want the horizontal lines to stop once they hit the plotted lines.

```
df<-data.frame(Points=c(-5.5,-1,-.5,0,.5,1,1.5,2,5.5),X=c(.002,.1,.15,.17,.18,.2,.25,.3,.7))

df2<-data.frame(Points=seq(-10,10,by=.1),X=c(0.01,  0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.04,   0.04,   0.04,   0.04,   0.04,   0.04,   0.04,   0.04,   0.04,   0.04,   0.04,   0.05,   0.05,   0.05,   0.05,   0.05,   0.05,   0.05,   0.06,   0.06,   0.06,   0.06,   0.06,   0.06,   0.06,   0.07,   0.07,   0.07,   0.07,   0.07,   0.08,   0.08,   0.08,   0.08,   0.09,   0.09,   0.09,   0.09,   0.1,    0.1,    0.1,    0.1,    0.11,   0.11,   0.11,   0.12,   0.12,   0.12,   0.13,   0.13,   0.15,   0.15,   0.15,   0.16,   0.16,   0.17,   0.17,   0.18,   0.18,   0.19,   0.19,   0.2,    0.2,    0.21,   0.22,   0.22,   0.22,   0.23,   0.23,   0.24,   0.25,   0.25,   0.26,   0.27,   0.28,   0.29,   0.3,    0.3,    0.31,   0.31,   0.32,   0.33,   0.34,   0.36,   0.36,   0.37,   0.38,   0.39,   0.39,   0.41,   0.42,   0.42,   0.44,   0.45,   0.46,   0.47,   0.48,   0.49,   0.5,    0.51,   0.52,   0.54,   0.55,   0.56,   0.57,   0.58,   0.59,   0.6,    0.61,   0.62,   0.64,   0.65,   0.66,   0.67,   0.68,   0.69,   0.7,    0.71,   0.73,   0.74,   0.75,   0.76,   0.77,   0.78,   0.79,   0.8,    0.81,   0.82,   0.83,   0.83,   0.84,   0.85,   0.86,   0.87,   0.88,   0.88,   0.89,   0.9,    0.9,    0.91,   0.92,   0.92,   0.93,   0.93,   0.94,   0.94,   0.95,   0.95,   0.96,   0.96,   0.96,   0.97,   0.97,   0.97))

ggplot(df2,aes(x=Points,y=X))+geom_line()+geom_hline(yintercept=df$X, col="red")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R's `approx` function is useful here. It receives known independent variable (df2$X), known dependent variable (df2$Points), and the new X  (df$X) for which we'd like a linear interpolation, and outputs in its `$y` the interpolated values. We can use these to be the end of our line segments.

```
df$Points2 = approx(df2$X, df2$Points, df$X)$y

ggplot(df2,aes(x=Points,y=X))+geom_line()+
  geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = Points2,
                   y = X, yend = X), color = "red",
               data = df)
```

[image]